# VertexColor shader is not working correctly in built application

Tags: unity, shaders, lighting

I want to change the vertex colors of my mesh. The light sources **must not affect** the objects with this shader, its lighting must be determined **only** by its vertices colors, so I turned the `Lighting Off`. I use this simple shader:

```
Shader "VertexColored/Simple" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
}

SubShader {
    Pass {
        ColorMaterial AmbientAndDiffuse
        Lighting Off

        SetTexture [_MainTex] {
            Combine texture * primary
        }
    }
}
Fallback "VertexLit"
}
```

And this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        Color[] exclrs = new Color[11]
        {
            new Color32(25, 25, 25, 255),
            new Color32(50, 50, 50, 255),
            new Color32(75, 75, 75, 255),
            new Color32(150, 150, 150, 255),
            new Color32(200, 200, 200, 255),

            new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255),

            new Color32(200, 200, 200, 255),
            new Color32(150, 150, 150, 255),
            new Color32(75, 75, 75, 75),
            new Color32(50, 50, 50, 255),
            new Color32(25, 25, 25, 255),
        };

        Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        Vector3[] normals = mesh.normals;

        Color[] colors = mesh.colors;

        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++, i++)
            {
                colors[i] = exclrs[j];
            }
            i--;
        }

        mesh.colors = colors;
    }
}
```

When the game is launched, in editor I can see this:
[image]

This is **EXACTLY** what I wanted to achieve!

But in built for PC(x86) version I see this:
[image]

Why the results from the editor and from the built .exe differs? What should I do to see my effect in built version? Maybe I need to use an another shader?

Answer (score 1):

`Fallback "VertexLit"` might be hiding an issue with the primary shader, although it looks fine to me. You should probably still remove that line until you know your main shader is working correctly.

My other guesses would be that the mesh colors are not being set for some reason. Are you using the `.sharedMesh` instead of `.mesh` accessor?

There's a lot of trial and error that you could do to simplify the problem, I think.

Comment: This is the likely culprit.  Check the quality settings in Edit -> Project -> Quality.  The highlighted row is what the editor is using, the green checkmark is the default for the target platform (columns).  It could be that the PC default is a "fast / poor" quality setting which causes shaders to use simpler fallbacks.